# Почему этот код прибавляет 2 вместо 1?

Tags: php, memcached

Добрый день, делаю запись в кеш:

```
            $memcache = new Memcache;
        $memcache->connect('localhost',11211);
        $memcache->set('count',$memcache->get( 'count' )+ 1);
        echo $memcache->get( 'count' );
```

В результате он увеличивается на 2 каждый раз, а не на 1. (Increment делает то же самое.)

В чём тут дело?
Спасибо.

Comment: Как вы определяете, что он увеличивается на два каждый раз? Откуда вызывается скрипт?

Comment: прям в index.php  -уже работает, когда добавил картинку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изначально значения с ключом `count` в хранилище нет, т.е. `$memcache->get( 'count' )` возвращает `false`. `false` преобразуется в 0 (особенность динамической типизации), т.е. `0 + 1 = 1`. При следующий итерации: `1 + 1 = 2`, далее `2 + 1 = 3,... n + 1`. Что характерно для обыкновенного инкремента со смещение (offset) в единицу:

```
$memcache = new \Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost',11211);
$memcache->set('count', 0);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    var_dump($memcache->increment('count'));
}
```

Comment: С первым разом я понял. А вот почему, если я запускаю скрипт, то выводятся значения на 2 больше предыдущего? Такое впечатление, что скрипт выполняется 2 раза

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, окей, хорошо, не хотите отвечать - буду колдовать на магишаре:

Скорее всего, у вас нет favicon.ico, вместо которой запрос из веб-браузера почему-то дергает ту же страницу.

Comment: ГЕНИАЛЬНО! Работает, когда иконку добавил! А я ещё думал, чего он скачает данные, а потом видно, что грузится ещё раз... Спасибо большое.

Comment: Особенность браузеров. Из серии, почему у меня данные дублируются в логе:)

Comment: @romeo, браузер все правильно делает. Настройщик сервера и страница-обработчик - нет.